# Analyze log file of dnsmasq

Tags: linux, logging, dns, dnsmasq

I current facing a problem. When I open the dnsmasq log, it looks like this:

```
Jun 10 17:50:00 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] isatap.lan from 115.34.22.160
Jun 10 17:50:00 dnsmasq[21796]: cached isatap.lan is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
Jun 10 17:50:21 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] isatap.lan from 115.34.22.160
Jun 10 17:50:21 dnsmasq[21796]: cached isatap.lan is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
Jun 10 17:50:31 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] isatap.lan from 115.34.22.160
Jun 10 17:50:31 dnsmasq[21796]: cached isatap.lan is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
Jun 10 17:50:37 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] isatap.lan from 115.34.22.160
Jun 10 17:50:37 dnsmasq[21796]: cached isatap.lan is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
Jun 10 17:50:40 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] zyx.qq.com from 115.34.22.160
Jun 10 17:50:40 dnsmasq[21796]: forwarded zyx.qq.com to 114.114.114.114
Jun 10 17:50:40 dnsmasq[21796]: forwarded zyx.qq.com to 223.5.5.5
Jun 10 17:50:40 dnsmasq[21796]: reply zyx.qq.com is 123.151.43.51
Jun 10 17:50:40 dnsmasq[21796]: reply zyx.qq.com is 183.60.62.158
Jun 10 17:50:40 dnsmasq[21796]: reply zyx.qq.com is 113.108.1.90
Jun 10 17:50:42 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] isatap.lan from 115.34.22.160
Jun 10 17:50:42 dnsmasq[21796]: cached isatap.lan is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
Jun 10 17:50:52 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] isatap.lan from 115.34.22.160
Jun 10 17:50:52 dnsmasq[21796]: cached isatap.lan is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
Jun 10 17:50:58 dnsmasq[21796]: query[A] ic.wps.cn from 115.34.22.160
AND ETC.
```

It's very difficult for us to analyze it. Anybody have a idea to only show the queried domain which should be like this?

```
isatap.lan
zyx.qq.com
ic.wps.cn
AND ETC.
```

However I tried this:
http://www.tannerwilliamson.com/analyzing-dnsmasq-log-with-awk/1610/

and its output i like this:

```
root@VM-208-178-ubuntu:/home# awk -f /home/dnsmasq.awk /var/log/dnsmasq.log | less
                                     name |      nb    |  forwarded |  answered from cache
                                irs01.net |         1  |         1  |         0
 927662-0-2081296634-261190004.ns.124-14-16-250-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net |         1  |         1  |         0
                         blog.sina.com.cn |         4  |         4  |         1
 927655-0-2081296634-261190004.ns.124-14-16-250-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn |         1  |         1  |         0
                            www.baidu.com |         2  |         2  |         0
*               careers.stackoverflow.com |        10  |        13  |         0
                blender.stackexchange.com |         2  |         2  |         0
 974449-0-2081296634-261190004.ns.124-14-16-250-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn |         1  |         1  |         0
                      img.iknow.bdimg.com |         2  |         1  |         1
*                           smarterer.com |         2  |         3  |         0
                          a.disquscdn.com |         1  |         1  |         0
 927648-0-2081296634-261190004.ns.124-14-16-250-ns.dns-spider.myxns.cn |         1  |         1  |         0
                physics.stackexchange.com |         6  |         5  |         4
*                area51.stackexchange.com |         2  |         3  |         0
                  iknow02.bosstatic.bdimg.com |         2  |         1  |         1
                       passport.baidu.com |         1  |         1  |         0
                    webapps.stackexchange.com |         5  |         4  |         4
```

It's little bit different from what I want. Anybody could help me?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @fedorqui I tried this: [link](http://www.tannerwilliamson.com/analyzing-dnsmasq-log-with-awk/1610/) but it's little bit different from what i want...

Comment: No, [edit] to show what you tried. Posts should contain [mcve] and be self-contained

Comment: @fedorqui I have changed it.

Comment: @WangTongze: `AND ETC.` is a valid line on the output or only the above three entries are valid?

Comment: @Inian Only the above three entries are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `awk` script could be sufficient for this, provided the logfile you showed remains intact.

```
awk '!seen[$6]++ {print $6}' file
```

will produce the output as

```
ic.wps.cn
isatap.lan
zyx.qq.com
```

The logic is simple, it parses each entry in column six and adds it into the array `seen` and prints the element only if it is not seen before.

P.S. If the order of the columns in the log file are subject to change in the future the `awk` command may not work, as it purely relies on the index of the column to get the results.